# How to translate and rotate drawing in html 5 without effecting another drawing?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

When I try to translate first drawing and keep second drawing fixed second drawing also moves so I am trying to keep second drawing fixed at specified position and only translate first drawing when I change value of first translate function .

My Code : -

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid 
      #d3d3d3;">
     Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
   </canvas>
   <script>
     var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
     var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  
     ctx.translate(10,10);
     ctx.fillRect(70,40,44,30);
     ctx.fillRect(10,10,40,30);
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid 
      #d3d3d3;">
     Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
   </canvas>
   <script>
     var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
     var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
     ctx.save();
     ctx.translate(10,10);
     ctx.fillRect(70,40,44,30);
     ctx.restore();
     ctx.fillRect(10,10,40,30);
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

You can use [save()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/save) and [restore()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/restore) . Before translate save the canvas state after you complete, restore it.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid 
      #d3d3d3;">
     Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
   </canvas>
   <script>
     var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
     var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  
     ctx.translate(10,10);
     ctx.fillRect(70,40,44,30);
     ctx.rotate(20*Math.PI/180);
     ctx.fillRect(10,10,40,30);
  </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```